# WinJS.UI.ListView not working in snapped view

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am using a `WinJS.UI.ListView` in a JavaScript project for Windows-8 Metro interface.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="myMain">
    <div id="myListTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
        <div class="myListViewItem">
            <p data-win-bind="innerText: description"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myListView"
        data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
        data-win-options="{ itemTemplate: myTemplate, layout: {type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout} }">
    </div>
 </div>
```

And part of the JavaScript:

```
ready: function (element, options) {
            // Set up the ListView.
            var myLView = myListView.winControl;
            WinJS.UI.setOptions(favoritesLView, {
                itemDataSource: dataSource,
                oniteminvoked: this.onItemInvoked.bind(this),
                selectionMode: WinJS.UI.SelectionMode.none
            });
        },
```

Where `dataSource` is where the list information is stored. It is a list obtained from:
`var myList = new WinJS.Binding.List(myJSONarray);`

The code is working in landscape and portrait view, but doesn't work when in snapped view. The list view appears empty despite `myList` has all the elements.

Is this a bug in Windows 8? Anybody know of a workaround to solve it?
I have found this link with the same problem but its solution doesn't work for me:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/winappswithhtml5/thread/ce8c722d-526b-4226-9e40-642ddb37422b

Comment: Could you post your CSS entries for the `@media` types, please? They might show some clues.

Comment: The `@media` types are empty. I removed them. I am trying to keep this example as simple as possible and find where the error is.
In the `@media` types what I was doing was just to adjust the margin-left and the width, nothing more...
In fact when I change to snapped I can see the div myListView, It is there but it is empty as I can check with the DOM explorer. But in the other views there is content.

Comment: Can you post your code for updateLayout or initializeLayout? Did you call updateLayout when the screen size changes?

Answer (score 0):

One reason that the ListView will not be displayed is if the element or any parent elements' display is set to "none". When the element becomes visible again, you will need to call listView.forceLayout(). See the explanation below from MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758352.aspx

> When you set the style.display property of a ListView or its parent
>   elements to "none", the app discards layout information about those
>   elements. When you change the value of the display property back to a
>   style that makes everything visible again, the app will layout all the
>   elements, but the ListView won't receive information about the current
>   layout and will have an invalid layout. You can fix the issue by
>   calling this function when you make the ListView visible again.